# connection between integrablity on the locally compact group and compact subgroup of it

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $G$ be an locally compact group with Haar measure $dx$ and $H$ is compact  subgroup of it with normalize Haar measure $dh$. If $F$ belong to $L^1(G)$, the restriction of $F$ to $H$ belong to $L^1(H)$ (i.e. $F$ is integrable respect to $dh$ on $H$)? Conversely, can we extend every member of $L^1(H)$ to some member of $L^1(G)$?

Comment: With respect to your first question, I don't see why it should.  Consider the case where $H$ has $G$-Haar measure zero,  $f$ is large on $H$,  and $f(g)=0$ for $g\notin H$.

Comment: @Timkinsella Then $f=0$ a.e. on $G$, hence $f\in L^1(G)$.

Comment: That's right, but $f\notin  L^1(H)$

Comment: @Timkinsella Perhaps I don´t remember the details, but is it not so that the Haar measure exists and is unique (up to a multiplicative constant)? Hence the Haar measure on $H$ is a projection of the Haar measure on $G$. What am I missing?

Comment: The first sentence is true.  And yes, there is a sort of Fubini theorem (I think it's called the Weil formula?) in the sense that you can integrate over G by integrating over the cosets of $H$ and the then integrating over $G/H$ (modulo some function you have to integrate against if $G$ isn't unimodular).

Comment: In any case where $H$ doesn't contain the whole identity component of $G$, though, $H$ will have $G$-Haar measure zero.

Comment: @AD Is it really true? "the Haar measure on H is a projection of the Haar measure on G". Are there the case that this is true?